# Find the integer $m$ such that $(\frac{1}{5})^m \cdot (\frac{1}{4})^ {24} = \frac{1}{2(10)^{47}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this problem

$$(\frac{1}{5})^m \cdot (\frac{1}{4})^ {24} = \frac{1}{2(10)^{47}}$$

and I need to find the integer $m$.

I know that I can write $5^m \cdot 4^{24} = 2(10)^{47} \Leftrightarrow 5^m = \frac{2(10)^{47}}{(1/4)^{24}}$, but I don't know how to go on from there.

It is a question in a GMAT test, so it should be possible to solve using basic operations (i.e. without logarithmic functions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Your equation can be written as:
$$
\frac{1}{5^m}\cdot \frac{1}{2^{48}}=\frac{1}{2\cdot2^{47} \cdot 5^{47}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Some hints:

$$\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^m = 5^{-m}$$

Likewise,

$$ \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{24} = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{48} = 2^{-48}$$

Change 10 on RHS to $2 \times 5$ and use the idea given in above expressions

Hence :

$$ \frac{1}{10^{47}} = \frac{1}{2^{47}\times 5^{47}} = 2^{-47} \times 5^{-47} $$

I hope you can finish it from here.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{2(10)^{47}}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2^{47}}\frac{1}{5^{47}}=\frac{1}{2^{48}}\frac{1}{5^{47}}=\frac{1}{4^{24}}\frac{1}{5^{47}}=\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{24}\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^{47}$$

Answer (score 0):

You started right; then note that $4=2^2$ and $10=2\cdot 5$, so your equation is
$$
5^m\cdot 2^{48}=2\cdot 2^{47}\cdot 5^{47}
$$

Comment: You are missing negative exponents!

Comment: @LaarsHelenius The OP had noticed that $1/a=1/b$ if and only if $a=b$; I think you can, too. `;-)`

Comment: I had a mistake in my calculation. My mistake.